# How to build a class structure, when members are also structured hierarchically?

Tags: php, inheritance, architecture, software-design, class-structure

I'm building a PHP web application, that should provide to the user a possiblity to order an "installation"/setup of a (ConnectDirect or File Transfer Gateway) connection between him and another person/organization.

(The technical specifica of the connection implementation are not important -- in the application it's only about the connections as  product, that can be ordered and managed.)

The classes hierarchy for its model layer should represent following real-world infrastructure:

- There are *connections*, that can be ordered.
- A connection can be an IBM Connect:Direct connnection or an IBM File Transfer Gateway connection.
- A *CD* connection is direct from A (*source*) to B (*target*).
- A *FTGW* connection consists *physically* of two connections: A (source) to the FTGW server and from the FTGW server to B (target) -- but *logically* (for the ordering user) it's also one connection.
- (There is additionally a case of an FTGW connection, that uses Connect:Direct as protokoll.)
- Every *endpoint* is either a source or a target.

So I see following logical elements: *logical connection*, *physical connection*, *role* (*source* and *target*), *connection type*, *order*, *endpoint*, *endpoint type* (CD and FTGW).

The structure I currently have looks like this:

[image: connections&endpoints pseudo UML class diagramm]

But there are some issues with it:

1. There are **two hierarchy trees**, where each **element** of the one **consists** contains elements of a particular **subset** of the other (each CD connection consists of CD endpoints; each FTGW connection consists of two FTGW endpoints, or more correctly: each FTGW logical connection consists of two physical FTGW connections -- and each of them consists of an FTGW endpoint and the FTGW server as second endpoint).

   An alternative might be to replace the relationship betweet `Endpoint` and `PsysicalConnection` by two relationships: `EndpointCD-PsysicalConnectionCD` and `EndpointFTGW-PsysicalConnectionFTGW`.

[image: replaced relationships]

**Pro**: More consistent; eliminates the logical imprecision (or maybe even *mistake*) of the faked possibility to build every connection (type) from a pair of any endpoints. **Contra**: Actually the requirement to contain two endpoints is a characteristic of every psysical connection -- from this point of view the right place for this is the very basic `PsysicalConnection` class.

2. Every **endpoint** can be **both** source and target and **contains** not only the common endpoint properties, but also **source and target properties**. That means, dependent on the currnt role of the endpoint some properties are **waste**. And this will also be influence the database structure (columns, that *sometimes* have to be set and *sometimes* have to bi `NULL`).

   An alternative is to extend the hierarchy...

   a. ...by classes like `EndpointSource` and `EndpoitTarget` inheriting directly from the `Endpoint` and being inherited by the classes `EndpointCD` and `EndpointFTGW` (that means: two identical subtrees -- under `EndpointSource` and under `EndpointTarget`);

   b. ...by classes like `EndpointCDSource` and `EndpointCDTarget` (inheriting from the class `EndpointCD`) and `EndpointFTGWSource`  and `EndpointFTGWTarget` (inheriting from the class `EndpointFTGW`) being inherited each by the concrete CD or FTGW endpoint classes (that means: twice two identical subtrees);

   c. ...by classes like `MyConcreteEndpoint***Source` and `MyConcreteEndpoint***Target` inheriting from the concrete endpoint classes (that means: every `MyConcreteEndpoint` class becomes abstract and gets two sublesses -- `MyConcreteEndpoint***Source` and `MyConcreteEndpoint***Target`, e.g. `EndpointCDLinux` is now abstract and is inherited by `EndpointCDLinuxSource` and `EndpointCDLinuxTarget`).

   **Pro**: eliminates the waste properties. **Contra**: A (more) complex class hierarchy.

Well, it's about software architecture and should (and of course will) be my design decision. But it would be nice to hear/read some expert (or non-expert) thougts, how to handle such a case. What are proper ways to organize the logical items for an infrastructure like what I described?

Comment: The bounty suggests you're looking for an answer drawing from credible and/or official sources, however that may be difficult to achieve without some degree of opinion or bias. Also, this is a very long description of a system design/architecture, I'm wondering if you'd have better luck if you broke it down into more easily digested separate questions which may be better for this Q&A format.

Comment: @inki Thank yoy for your comment. Yes, the bounty suggestion "answer from credible and/or official sources" actually might be a bit confucing here. I simply didn't find any better / more suitable option. About breaking the question down into less questions: Sure, I usually try to ask questions in way (following something like "[single responsibility principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single_responsibility_principle)"). But in this case I have no idea, how to shorten the question -- it's long, but all its content is its description and some thougts to the problem.

Comment: Did you try to start modelling from the other end? I see only data here. What is it for? Where is a **behaviour**, **use-cases**? Or do you simply need straight mapping from data to some objects (which is quite useless)?

Comment: Woah. I know how I'd do it - but even with ten years experience as a middleware solution architect, I would not call my modelling of these objects anything but personal preference. And frankly, I'd shy away from modelling such complicated structures in PHP. Although I might make sure that my PHP objects reflect a structure designed in some back end application.

Comment: What I see is in my opinion what you are trying to model hardware specifics too close to such thing as class hierarchy.

Maybe you should try to abstract your class hierarchy from actual *concreate* specifics of particular domain logic.

Final strcuture will of course contains similar *concrete* classes as you defined.

but istead of building 2+ parallel hierarchies it is simplied to use such thing as interfaces, builders and factories to manage, build and validate possible configurations, while hierarchy is not bound to domain logics "with nails".

Answer (score 1):

Maybe I am overthinking, but I suggest for you to use slightly different model to reflect your business logic.

Following could be a total misunderstanding, but I'll give it a shot.

So:

Basing on what in fact any connection is, here is a concept:

- Every connection is a collection of Nodes through which data should travel in order to reach its destination.
- Each node can connect with next node using specific protocol, which is specific only to direct connection between two particular nodes.
- Protocol has its own properties common for source and target nodes

Basing on this I suggest following model of building, managing and storing a configuration of Product:

[image]

Here:

- LogicalConnection is reference to built composition of actual Connection, Node and Protocol classes
- Connection contains a double-linked list of Nodes which are composed in order as data flows. i.e.: 1st element is source node and 2nd is its target and so on.
- Concrete Node contains platform specific configuration, reference to target (*Node), source node (*Node) and concrete protocol (*Protocol)
- Protocol contains its specific configuration for source and target, Node instances may refer to Protocol instance to extract required configuration.
- Target and Source Nodes "see" each-other and source-target protocol configuration via double-linked list structure.
- Configurations\*ConfigBuilder implementations orchestrate process of accepting data from UI and transforming it into actual composition of Connection, Node and Protocol depending on case.
- IBM\ConnectDirect\ and IBM\FTGW\ namespaces contain concrete realizations for Protocol and *Node (e.g. WindowsNode, UnixNode)

If there still is a need for Node or Protocol to contain both source and target related attributes and part of them still could be NULL in some configurations - I suggest to use EAV storage model for DB if there is any concern about unused columns etc..

Using suggested model connections you described in question could be represented as following:

```
Connection:IBM_CD {
  nodes:[
    {//LinuxNode
      target:*nextElement,
      protocol:{//IBM.ConnectDirect.Protocol
        ..target attributes..
        ..source attributes..
      }
      ..platform specific attributes..
    },
    {//WindowsShareNode
      target:*nil,
      protocol:{
        //IBM.ConnectDirect.Protocol(same instance or null)
      }
      ..platform specific attributes..
    },
  ]
}

Connection:IBM_FTGW {
  nodes:[
    {//LinuxNode
      target:*nextElement,
      source:*nil,
      protocol:{//IBM.FTGW.Protocol
        ..target attributes..
        ..source attributes..
      }
      ..platform specific attributes..
    },
    {//IntermediateServerLinuxNode
      target:*nextElement,
      source:*prevElement,
      protocol:{//IBM.FTGW.Protocol
        ..target attributes..
        ..source attributes..
      },
      ..platform specific attributes
    },
    {//WindowsShareNode
      target:*nil,
      source:*prevElement,
      protocol:*nil,
      ..platform specific attributes..
    }
  ]
}
```